# gmapping doesn't publish the tf from map->odom

Tags: navigation, husky, gmapping, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently try to run SLAM gmapping on Husky robot. I build the map successfully but don't get the tf from map to odom.
Even the frame "map" doesn't exist.

I have some the questions.

1. whether the time synchronization has an impact on that?

I have used the command "ntpdate -p robot_ip" to check it. I get the following result.

server 192.168.5.112, stratum 0, offset 0.000000, delay 0.00000
8 May 10:23:58 ntpdate[4259]: no server suitable for synchronization found

2. whether rate of publishing tf  has an impact on that?

I tried to change the value of parameter "transform_publish_period" of gmapping so that it is consistent with the rate of others publishing.

All trials don‘t resolve my problem. What’s wrong? Thanks for any advise.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261255/gmapping-doesn%27t-publish-the-tf-from-map-%3Eodom/) by [Shanan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30289/shanan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-05-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-05-09**:
Please attach tf tree and node graph

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2017-05-09**:
Also check your laser scanner. There may be a problem with readings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks all.  Because gmaping published the tf message that was sent to robot through wifi, but tf messages do not deal with low bandwidth networks well. I install gmapping package into robot, and my computer only is responsible to visualize the built map. All work fine.
Reference website: http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Design

I revised the provided launch files in gmapping package according to my need. It is easy to ignore "use_sim_time" parameter which usually is set as true in launch file.  In here, Its value should be set as false.
Reference website: http://wiki.ros.org/Clock

---

Originally posted by [Shanan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30289/shanan/) with karma: 26 on 2017-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amrita Suresh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28256/amrita-suresh/) on 2020-12-14**:
I have a similar problem. I can see in my tf tree that the transform /map -> /odom is being broadcasted by /slam_gmapping. But when I try to listen to this transform using  `tf2_ros::BufferInterface::lookupTransform("/map", "/odom", ros::Time(0))`,
I get the warning
`"zoe/map" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.`
Can you help?